# Import MS-Access data file to make the searchable page

Tags: plugins, library, books

I have an MS-access data file the contains the Books detail (used in my library). I want to import this data file to Wordpress page in such a way that user can sear the books with reference such as author, book title, and even either book is available (borrowed) in the library or not.

I search for the plugin but not found.

Please guide what should be done for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want your WP site to be able to search this Access Database?

If so, then you would need to get your access database data into the WP database.

Multiple ways to accomplish this:

1. ACF. You can use Advanced Custom Fields. Setup custom fields for your Books data and enter you data. You did not say how large your data is so this might not be a good option if you have a lot of data.
2. create a custom WP database table. create the table based on your Access database. You can convert your Access database into a CSV file and then upload to your custom DB table. Now you can create a custom page template, will need to write custom code for this custom page template to search this new database table and return results on this page.
3. If you want this Books data to be searchable throughout the WordPress site then you can import your Books data as WordPress data such as a Custom Post Type. Once you setup your new Books CPT and get your Books data into the WP database tables, then the Books data will be searchable throughout the website.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @phptherightway. I am not a too advanced user of WordPress. Can you further guide how to import the WordPress database (some specific fields only such as author name, book title, publication year, publisher, etc.), and how to make it searchable?